# My ETH gets sweeped in milliseconds by a bot, what are the mechanics behind this?

Tags: blockchain, txpool, flashbots

Long story short, i had my ethereum private key pushed on github by accident during development.
The funds by themselves are no realy my main concern. However, i noticed that whenever i attempt to send funds to that address, it gets sweeped in an instant.

The block explorer shows this transaction also having 3 dropped transactions at the very same block.

It makes me wonder.

1: How can the funds be sweeped in the same block as it was sent (unconfirmed) as there was no balance left in the account

2: Why did the block had 3 dropped transactions

I've searched github and stack, but i can't find any code that can reproduce this behaviour. Can anyone explain me the mechanics behind this, if possible, share some code so i can learn and explore this? This goes way beyond monitoring transactions and just sending a simple tx with the total balance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "Ethereum is a dark forest".

Before a transaction is mined, it is exchanged between nodes, who keep it into what is called the mempool. Anyone with a connected node can look at the mempool and filter for your compromised address.

Your attacker does just that, it sees your funding transaction in the mempool, takes the nonce (transaction sequence) and immediately issues a draining transaction with nonce+1 (so that it is ordered by miners right after the funding) and a very high gas price (so that it does not linger).

In fact you have more than 1 attacker. They all do the same, but there can be only 1 winner. Hence the other failed transactions.